# ie 8 problem with custom google font

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I'm working on a [site](http://asian-monitor.com/~robert/betcatcher/), using custom google fonts, but in ie8 not working or just partially(left content good, and a right content, ajax, not so good) any suggestion or idea why not so good?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer, I forgot about compability...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just saw your website in compatibility mode in IE8 of my IE9, and I do not see any font problems.
I run window 7, cna you please post a picture of your problems?

[image]

**UPDATE:** I forgot an important thing... to check about compability. IE7 and IE8 have only "partial" compability with font-face.

To solve the issue you have to use a code similar to this, and convert fonts

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?') format('eot'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

**Google is using only woff**, while you have to load eot, trutype and svg as well for full crossbrowser compability.

**You can convert fonts easily** at [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator), download the font from
http://themes.googleusercontent.com/font?kit=tMrhQDUBAHnnGuM33-yobPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA

**For more information on the matter**: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

Comment: In IE9 it working fine,if you use IE8, not IE9 with IE8 compatible, not working and I don't know why.

Comment: I cannot test on IE8 native at the moment, but I think that I solved the issue with my update answer

Comment: The problem was the opacity, I used jquery animation to hide and show the content. after I uncommented this animation,the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In IE9 and IE7 compatibility mode using IE9 it shows fine; in IE8 and IE7 compatibility mode using IE8 it looks very bad so I would have to conclude that it´s some obscure bug in IE8 itself.

I don´t think there's much you can do about that so to solve it I would just use conditional comments to address IE8 and IE7 and use `verdana` for that section. And hope they go away soon...

Answer (score 0):

FOR IE10 and below and for all other browsers use

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?'); 
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```