# IE Problem with True Type Font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I intalled a new font on my website but I cannot get IE8 and IE9 to recognize, I have no knoledge on how the browsers render the fonts, but my css style sheet font declaration is as follows,

```
@font-face {     


font-family: VAGRounded;     src: url("../fonts/VAGRoundedW01-Light.eot") /* EOT file for IE */

 src:url("../fonts/VAGRoundedW01-Light.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype');


 }

@font-face {  font-family: VAGRounded;  src: url("../fonts/VAGRoundedW01-Light.TTF") format('truetype'),

url("../fonts/VAGRoundedW01-Light.svg#webfontmvIrHXJB") format('svg');
```

Much help is appreciated!!

Comment: possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472207/ie-8-problem-with-custom-google-font

Comment: see this: http://raptor.hk/custom-font-in-website/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 and IE9 do not support embedded fonts via the CSS3 scheme without first converting into supported formats (SVG, TT, EOT, etc.). **EDIT**: IE8 and IE9 requires tweaks to support embedded fonts. See the comments on your question since it's a duplicate.

FYI IE10 will be the first IE browser to support the HTML5 standard.

There are nifty other methods of embedding fonts. The one I recommend is Cufon because it uses VML in older browsers and doesn't require flash.

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: How about IE8?  , I just uploaded my font and gave a javascript as output , how would I go about installing this ?

Comment: There's some installation instructions for Cufon here: https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Usage and if you're using Wordpress a Cufon plugin was created too http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cufon/

Comment: I am using joomla, I need this new font to be available to only the menu of my template, not the whole site

Comment: if its your navigation menu you'll need it for the whole site anyways so include in your template. Just use low-level header tags like <h4> and you can format it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a service like Font Squirrel.

It generates all the code for the various browsers.

Output would look something like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LivingstoneRegular';
    src: url('../livingst-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../livingst-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('../livingst-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../livingst-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../livingst-webfont.svg#webfont44PDl6Sr') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: Thanks , but seems that my font is blocked

Answer (score 0):

Try a proper syntax: [Fontspring Syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax), [Further Hardening of the Bulletproof Syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax), [Mo’ Bulletproofer](http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/), or [Smiley](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax).