# embedded font on website won't display in IE or Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, font-face

I have the following font setup in the CSS for a wordpress based site I'm building and the fonts display fine in FF, but not at all in IE(9) or Chrome(latest).

```
  /* =Typography
  -------------------------------------------------------------- */
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Humanist';
      src: url('fonts/humanist521lightbt-webfont.eot');
      src: url('fonts/humanist521lightbt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('fonts/humanist521lightbt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('fonts/Humanist521LightBT.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('fonts/humanist521lightbt-webfont.svg#webfontregular') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
  }

  @font-face {
      font-family: 'HumanistIT';
      src: url('fonts/humanist521lightitalicbt-webfont.eot');
      src: url('fonts/humanist521lightitalicbt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('fonts/humanist521lightitalicbt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('fonts/Humanist521LightItalicBT.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('fonts/humanist521lightitalicbt-webfont.svg#webfontregular') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
  }

  @font-face {
     font-family: 'HumanistBo';
     src: url('fonts/humanist777blackbt-webfont.eot');
     src: url('fonts/humanist777blackbt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/humanist777blackbt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/Humanist777BlackBT.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/humanist777blackbt-webfont.svg#webfontregular') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
  }
```

When I need to use the font for an element, I just add `font-family: 'Humanist', Arial, sans-serif;`

The fonts are stored in the theme's directory in folder called "fonts".

Am I doing something wrong or missing something for it to work with other browsers?

Thanks

Comment: updated code.  Now only have issues in Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer 9 and less has some issues displaying `.TTF` files. It does not support embedded fonts via the CSS3 scheme without first converting into supported formats (`.svg`, `.ttf`, `.eot`, etc.). However, you can [tweak your @Font-Face Syntax to support this](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax).

With Chrome not displaying the correct font, this is due to different browsers having different needs. You can find more information in the second link in the more information below.

A side note as well: if your font is hosted on [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/), embed a link into your website instead of hosting it yourself.

**TLDR; need a comprehensive list of @font-face types**

More information:

[SO Question - IE problems with True Type Font files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290560/ie-problem-with-true-type-font)

[SO Question - Font-Face problem in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051826/font-face-problem-in-chrome)

[Further Hardening of the Bulletproof Syntax - Fontspring](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax).

[Bulletproof @font-face syntax - Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

Comment: Thanks

I read another persons question and came across font squirrel.
I've updated my code to include the converted fonts...

There is still an issue with Chrome though.

Comment: Is it not displaying in Chrome still? Can I ask what fonts you are using (as in `.ttf`, `.svg`, `.eot`, etc)?

Comment: Fixed!   I had to add the MIME type for woff to IIS

Comment: @ReeceDodds I was about to say had you seen [this question!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts/4657091#4657091) Heh, good to hear :).

Answer (score 0):

To use the font for an HTML element, then we need to use the @font-face rule of power full features of CSS3 that supported in many modern browser. CSS property font-family of HTML is used to defined the font name which we want to embed ans src property used to defined the path of the font to be embed.

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: myfont;
    src: url('(fontfile.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('(fontfile.woff') format('woff'),
         url('(fontfile.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('(fontfile.svg#(fontfile') format('svg');
}

div,h2
{
    font-family:myfont;
}
```