# Font-face, Raphael and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, svg, raphael, font-face

I am desesperatly trying to get some google font faces to work with Raphael (SVG / VML rendering JavaScript library) on IE8.

At first i tried the google fonts code.

My second try has been to download and convert the fonts to host my own more complete css. Now the fonts show in the html part of the page (inside a modified bootstrap nav dropdown), but it does not work in the VML canvas (generated by Raphael).

Example here :

http://beta.yetiprint.com/fr/etiquettes-autocollantes/4-etiquettes-couleur-ronde.html

Is it possible to get that working in iE8? Any clue?

Comment: try to import `eot` fonts (Open Type) to see if they work and further debug this. it's documented at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533034(v=vs.85).aspx). i'm trying to figure out the problem for some time now, and so far it's the only promising lead. hope to solve this later..

Comment: i'm getting pessimistic, after reading [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/gfx.html#implementation-notes) that IE had dropped support for `font-family` on VML after version 7.

Comment: also, check out [this thread on `eot` fonts in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472207/ie-8-problem-with-custom-google-font) and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your links :) I am still trying to find a solution. I dont even know if its possible... I will let you know my progress here.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that ScottS’s method works, but I could not fit these instructions in his answer’s comment field.

Instructions for getting custom fonts to work in Raphael by using Cufón:

1. Go to the [Cufón website](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) where you can convert a font to path shapes.
2. Upload your custom font, choose a font name, and click the Raphael icon at “Customization for 3rd-party scripts”.
3. Submit the form and download the Javascript file that pops up.
4. Include this Javascript below the Raphael Javascript include.
5. [Register the font](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.getFont) with Raphael like this, where fontname is the name of your font that you specified in step 2: `var myfont = paper.getFont('fontname');`
6. [Use your font](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.print) like this in Raphael: `paper.print(100, 100, 'Hello World', myfont, 100);`

Performance is not great compared to [`Paper.text`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.text), but it works in IE6 and up.

Comment: Good stuff - it works like a charm, and yeah - performance is worse. Another difference is that Paper.text centers text around the point you specify. Paper.print just renders it from this point.

Comment: Also I think it shuold be accepted answer as there is no other way to make custom fonts work with Raphael.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the procedures in Raphael to `registerFont()`? See http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.registerFont. That gives the procedure for getting the font into Raphael.

Based off [the link in that page](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about), you should be able to get VML support and thus IE8 functionality. At least theoretically; I've never done it, I just found this information which seems to point in the direction you want to go.